# Two onClick events: slideDown and scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a page and I need to have two events on onClick: slideDown (so a different section becomes visible) and ScrollTop so the page scrolls down automatically after the above section becomes visible, with focus on the button.

I have the codes:

```
    {% if product.addons|length > 0 %}
    <button class="bb-button bb-button-submit bb-button-big" type="submit" id="order-button">{% trans 'Continue' %}</button>
    {% else %}
    <button class="bb-button bb-button-submit bb-button-big" type="submit" id="order-button">{% trans 'Order now' %}</button>
    {% endif %}
```

and

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

if($(".addons").length && $(".addons").is(':hidden')) {
    $('#order-button').one('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.addons').slideDown('fast');
        return false;
    });
}

$('#period-selector').change(function(){
    $('.period').hide();
    $('.period.' + $(this).val()).show();
}).trigger('change');

$('.addon-period-selector').change(function(){
    var r = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#' + r + ' span').hide();
    $('#' + r + ' span.' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
}).trigger('change');

});
</script>
```

but I don't know how to add the scrollTop event in the same time, so the page scrolls down to the "Order now" button.

Comment: Why don't you post working code here? Why can't you add code to scroll immediately after slide?

Comment: See [this page](http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/how-to-scroll-elements-smoothly-in-javascript-jquery-without-plugins/). It might give you some ideas.

Comment: The element here is defined by button id which is order-button in both cases. The scroll only happens up to the first button -> "Continue" and not to the second button -> "Order now" after it becomes visible. I have managed to initiate the slideDown and scrollTop but the scroll is only done up to "Continue". Changing the button ID's break functionality.